# Undefined behavior when creating a new object at the storage location that a const object occupies

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, placement-new

Regarding to the C++ [standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) ,Creating a new object at the storage location that a const object with static, thread, or automatic storage
duration occupies or, at the storage location that such a const object used to occupy before its lifetime ended results in undefined behavior
There is the following example

```
struct B {
B();
~B();
};
const B b;
void h() {
b.~B();
new (const_cast<B*>(&b)) const B; // undefined behavior
}
```

My question is why this example results in UB? The placement new is used after explicitly call the destructor of object B.

Comment: Because many implementations have a concept of write-protected memory regions, where the variable can be placed into.

Comment: UB means that the implementor of the language remain free to design the way he wants. So whatever behavior you imagine or experimentally observe cannot be taken for granted.

Comment: Something is UB by definition, not by empirical data. In other words: It is UB because the standard says so. The motivation for the standard to decide to make it UB is a guess for non-committee members, albeit it may be an educated guess, the more insight one has into current compiler implementations.

Comment: Conceptually a `const` object is one that does not and cannot change, doing various hacks to violate that property means that the property becomes meaningless. So, the language can either accept the hacks with the result that `const` becomes a meaningless tag that may as well be removed from the language, or the hack can be declared "Undefined Behavior".

Comment: @bitmask: If the Standard says something is UB, all that means is that nothing an implementation does in response would render it *non-conforming*.  It does not imply any judgment as to whether some ways of processing the action might make an implementation *more or less suitable for some particular purposes* than would others.